# Как правильно хранить лист строк в базе данных?

Tags: java, mysql

Есть база данных - MySQL. В ней есть таблица. В одной из колонок мне нужно хранить список строк. Первое, что приходить на ум это сделать из моего листа строк одну строку через запятую и хранить её в базе как строку, а при получении из бд - сплитить по запятой, но такое ощущение, что это костыль. Может для этого есть более нормальные способы?

Comment: для каких целей храниться этот список. возможно ли редактирование какой то отдельной строки из списка, независимо от остальных. Реляционная модель предполагает, что заводится отдельная таблица, в которой хранятся строки по одной в записи с ссылкой на id сущности из основной таблицы. Но бывают случаи (довольно редкие), когда это излишне

Comment: В данном случае строки хранятся просто как данные, они не будут изменяться, разве что только добавляться, а так - просто будут выводится в textArea (javafx).

Comment: Если это тупо кусок текста, то тогда проще его так же одним куском и хранить. Смысл разделять есть когда вам надо например по запросу от клиента удалить именно 3ю строку не трогая остальные

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если строки будут добавляться, то создайте отдельную таблицу под эти строки.

Если хранить все в одной ячейке, то чтобы добавить 1 строку придется вычитать все прошлые в память, дописать нужную и все вместе сохранить. А ведь задача сохранить только 1 строку.

Работая с отдельной таблицей, сохранения будет быстрым, доставание всех строк займет примерно тоже время.